# How can I list local users on a Windows Server 2003 including Description and Full Name from command line?

Tags: windows-server-2003

I need a full list of local users defined on a Windows Server 2003. It is not a part of an AD domain. I have found typing "NET USER" on the command line lists all users, but it does not include the Description or Full Name field, which I need. I can't find any command line option for it either.

It doesn't HAVE to be command line. The clue is I need to copy-paste the data into a processable format. The Computer Manager console is not a fan of copy pasting.

Answer (score 3):

Copy this into a **.JS** file.

```
var objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2");

var listLocalUsers = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * from Win32_UserAccount Where LocalAccount = True");

for(var enumLocalUser = new Enumerator(listLocalUsers); !enumLocalUser.atEnd(); enumLocalUser.moveNext()){
    var localUser = enumLocalUser.item();
    WScript.Echo("Short Name: " + localUser.Name);
    WScript.Echo("Full Name: " + localUser.FullName);
    WScript.Echo("Description: " + localUser.Description);
    WScript.Echo("\n");
}
```

VB example:
    On Error Resume Next 
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\.\root\cimv2") 
    Set listLocalUsers = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_UserAccount Where LocalAccount = True")

```
For Each localUser in listLocalUsers 
    Wscript.Echo "Short Name: " & localUser.Name 
    Wscript.Echo "Full Name: " & localUser.FullName 
    Wscript.Echo "Description: " & localUser.Description 
    Wscript.Echo "\n"
Next
```

Then run it using `cscript myGetLocalUsers.js` or `cscript myGetLocalUsers.vb` at the command prompt.

Edit:

I haven't tested it so let me know if you get any errors.

Comment: The VB Script part worked, except I had to change `objItem.Name` to `localuser.Name`. Thanks very much! I also did some changes so that it's saved to file instead of displayed in message boxes. Final script here, for anyone interested: https://gist.github.com/1992686

Comment: Just for the record the JS script gave an error on line 1 char 1, but might be something I did wrong. Never mind though, solved the problem.

Comment: The JS script works just fine for me. Glad that it worked out.

Comment: After running the script, the `wmiprvse.exe` network service process pegged itself to 99% CPU and had to be terminated. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933593 Microsoft acknowledges this behavior and furnishes a hotfix.